# How to vertically align non-monospaced text

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create two columns of left-aligned text with a variable-width font. My current process:

1. Measure the string that will be going into the first column
2. Subtract its width from the maximum width of said first column to get the difference
3. Divide that with the width of a single space to get the number of spaces needed
4. Right-pad the result with the necessary number of spaces

This feels logically sound to me, but the output looks like this (with a variable-width font):

```
a                    12345678910
as                  12345678910
asd                12345678910
asdf               12345678910
asdfg             12345678910
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
a          12345678910
as         12345678910
asd        12345678910
asdf       12345678910
asdfg      12345678910
```

What am I missing?

```
const int maxNameWidth = 150;

Font measurementFont;
Graphics graphics;
float spaceWidth;

void Main()
{
    measurementFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
    spaceWidth = graphics.MeasureString(" ", measurementFont).Width;

    addRow("a", "12345678910");
    addRow("as", "12345678910");
    addRow("asd", "12345678910");
    addRow("asdf", "12345678910");
    addRow("asdfg", "12345678910");

    measurementFont.Dispose();
    graphics.Dispose();
}

void addRow(string name, string value) {
    float width = graphics.MeasureString(name, measurementFont).Width;
    int amountOfSpacesNeeded = Convert.ToInt32((maxNameWidth - width) / spaceWidth);
    Console.WriteLine(name + " ".PadRight(amountOfSpacesNeeded) + content); // The console font is Arial
}
```

**Edit**: Fixed dumb error with padding `name` instead of actually multiplying the amount of spaces. The result is a lot better now, but still a bit off. I do notice that the width of five spaces is not equal to the `spaceWidth * 5` though...

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: @GaurangDave Edited to show it.

Comment: can you please put "Console.WriteLine()" commands in between lines and show values of every calculation before and after doing something. check the numbers to see if they are doing the right thing. or you can use debug tools too but this is the easiest way. if you cant find solution I (or anyoneelse) may come back later to find the problem. If you find an aswer before we do so, post answer too.

Comment: This is strange. Are you really using Ariel on the console? Anyway, this approach will not work well with variable width fonts because most often the space needed between columns will not be an even multiple of the width of the space character. The correct approach is to draw each individual column string at an exact pixel offset.

Comment: @glenebob Yup, I'm using LinqPad to run this which allows me to change the font family and size of the console output. The spacing you mentioned is indeed true--and there isn't a way to estimate and include it in the calculations too, is there? Unfortunately I can't use actual drawing for where I'm using this code (text only environment) but I'll keep that in mind if it's available next time, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'vertical' alignment. You want 'left'  alignment. And indeed, measuring single characters is not reliable method. You could measure 10 and then dived. Also spaces are slimmer than most other characters. 'n'-space is closer to the average, but you should really measure the whole target string. ((Or pixel measure each character on the console by doing screenshots; arrg..)) - Possible workaround: Temporarily switch to fixed-font and set position directly; the print with the Arial fornt..

Comment: Curious: Do you see any use of this outside of LinqPad?? Also: Just noticed that Console.SetCursorPosition won't work inside of LinqPad, so no workaround there..

Comment: @TaW I was actually trying to send a message formatted like this from a Discord bot. Without the paid font that Discord uses though this is unfortunately useless for that purpose, but perhaps it can be used for similar things (or when Discord allows us to choose which font we want to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author has added his own solution while I was working on this code. Yet, though his code seems to do its work, it adds to the complexity of the solution. My code has a much simpler algorithm.

```
void addRows(string name, string value)
{
    string teststring = name + "";
    int spacesAdded = 0;
    while (maxNameWidth > graphics.MeasureString(teststring + "x", measurementFont).Width)
    {
        spacesAdded++;
        teststring += " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(":" + name + " ".PadRight(spacesAdded) + ":" + value + ":" + spacesAdded);
}
```

I used the "x" to get a similar result as his and it can be replaced by other characters to test with more strings to see if it works. I have tested the with only 2 extra strings that include very wide "ooooo" and very narrow "....." to get a satisfying result.

---

PS: It seems I previously thought differently while answering. Since I am also trying to learn new things and to find new approaches, I tried to get a result for this question. Anyways, this time I am on the right path

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed make the code a lot cleaner! It would be fine to compress it even further and just add spaces directly to `name` and skip the `PadRight` call entirely. I'm guessing that it's probably not too inefficient to be concatenating spaces ourselves for just a few strings (no idea how `PadRight` is implemented)?

Comment: thanks for accepting as the answer. I had commented on your answer that there is a bug of width for a single character. I later noticed mine has a similar but bug too. if you try to write total spaces inserted, mine will give 24 for "a" and yours 27. it is caused how we compare the width. can you please try to fix in both codes and offer an edit to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it. However I think that this solution is disgusting trash so I'll keep this question opened until someone has a nicer/less brute force method.

Basically, since the calculations get me 1-2 spaces off due to incalculable kerning (as far as I can google), I just measure the string again and add or subtract spaces from it until it reaches the opposite side of `maxNameWidth` from its direction; eg. if it's too short then then add a space, measure again and see if that's over `maxNameWidth`, if yes then stop, and vice versa.

Full code:

```
const int maxNameWidth = 150;

Font measurementFont;
Graphics graphics;
float spaceWidth, xWidth;

enum Direction { None, FromHigh, FromLow };

void Main()
{
    measurementFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1));
    spaceWidth = graphics.MeasureString(" ", measurementFont).Width;
    xWidth = graphics.MeasureString("x", measurementFont).Width;

    addRow("a", "12345678910");
    addRow("as", "12345678910");
    addRow("asd", "12345678910");
    addRow("asdf", "12345678910");
    addRow("asdfg", "12345678910");

    measurementFont.Dispose();
    graphics.Dispose();
}

void addRow(string name, string value) {

    float width = graphics.MeasureString(name, measurementFont).Width;
    int amountOfSpacesNeeded = Convert.ToInt32((maxNameWidth - width) / spaceWidth);

    string firstColumn = name + " ".PadRight(amountOfSpacesNeeded);
    float currWidth;
    Direction dir = Direction.None;
    while (true) {
        // I add an 'x' here because just measuring a bunch of spaces does not work (the width of one space is apparently equal to the width of five according to graphics)
        currWidth = graphics.MeasureString(firstColumn + "x", measurementFont).Width - xWidth;
        if (((dir == Direction.FromLow) || (dir == Direction.None)) && (currWidth < maxNameWidth)) {
            dir = Direction.FromLow;
            firstColumn += " ";
        }
        else if (((dir == Direction.FromHigh) || (dir == Direction.None)) && (currWidth > maxNameWidth)) {
            dir = Direction.FromHigh;
            firstColumn = firstColumn.Remove(firstColumn.Length - 1);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(firstColumn + value);

}
```

Output (paste somewhere with 14pt Arial to see the alignment):

```
a                     12345678910
as                   12345678910
asd                 12345678910
asdf                12345678910
asdfg              12345678910
```

Comment: after my failing attempts, I was working on a solution. please read that too.

Comment: I was about to accept your answer but it does have a bug you missed. the width of "x" is calculated incorrect (xwidth). remember 5*"x" is not equal to "xxxxx", this is because extra pixels around characters. when compared to my solution, yours add 3 more spaces because of this bug. it is not important for small projects, but may affect greatly on bigger ones.